# Andengine: game 15 and number image movement

Tags: android, andengine

I've setted al number image in the image grid, now the problem is how to move number image with a "module" of 50pixel (the dimension of a single cell grid) just where there's a free cell?
I'm using Andengine and each number image is a Sprite and grid image is one as well.

**EDIT:** I'm working in this way:

I set the tile position with this two functions:

```
private void getGrid()
{
    boolean end     =   false;
    Random random   =   new Random();

    int x = 0;
    while( ALDef.size() < 15 && x < 100 )
    {
        // Genera un numero a caso, da 1 a 15
        int numRandom       =   random.nextInt( 15 );

        System.out.println( x++ + ") Scelgo un numero RANDOM:" + numRandom );

        // il numero e' gia' presente in array?
        if ( !memory.contains( numRandom ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "ADD " + numRandom );
            // Non e' presente...
            ALDef.add( numRandom );
            memory.add( numRandom );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "ESISTE " + numRandom );
            memory.add( numRandom );
        }
    }

    System.out.println( "------------------------------" );
}

// ===========================================================
// Restituisce le coordinate
// ===========================================================
public HashMap getCoordinates( int numInArray )
{
    // Ottiene l'integer corrispondente a numInArray, ovvero il tasto
    Integer value       =   ALDef.get( numInArray );

    int row         =   0; // riga della tabella
    int position    =   0; // posizione
    // Definisce la riga
    if ( numInArray <= 3 )
    {
        row         =   0;
        position    =   3 - ( 3 - numInArray );
    }
    else if ( numInArray >= 4 && numInArray <= 7 )
    {
        row     =   1;
        position    =   numInArray - 4;
    }
    else if ( numInArray >= 8 && numInArray <= 11 )
    {
        row     =   2;
        position    =   numInArray - 8;
    }
    else if ( numInArray >= 12 && numInArray <= 15 )
    {
        row     =   3;
        position    =   numInArray - 12;
    }

    HashMap HM      =   new HashMap();
    HM.put( "btn" , value );
    HM.put( "x" , width * position );
    HM.put( "y" , height * row );

    System.out.println( "Colloco il numero " + ( value ) + " nella casella " + numInArray + "(ROW=" + row + ",POS=" + position + ")" );

    return HM;
}
```

The logic of this two functions is that getGrid put in an ArrayList random numbers (from 0 to 15) that corresponding to the tile number image.
With getCoordinates the function return the coordinate (in row - 0, 1, 2, 3 - and position - 0, 1, 2, 3) of the tile to istantiate the sprite.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're keeping track of your cells with a 2D array `Cell[4][4] cells`, you can initialize your cells and have `emptyCellLocation = (emptyCell.row, emptyCell.col)`. Then you can determine which cell you want to drag and only allow it to move to `emptyCellLocation`. Make sure you update `emptyCellLocation`.

Comment: I set the tile position throught the script I wrote on the first post, check it please

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your code. I would consider introducing objects like `Tile` and `Grid`.